# \omega and W different

Tags: math-mode

I want to have a different symbol (stated 2 in the picture) from `\omega` (stated 1 in the picture) and text `W`.

[image]

However, when I did this:

```
\begin{equation}
    STFT\{{x(t)}\}(\tau, \omega) = X(\tau , \omega) =  \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}x(t)w(t - \tau) e^{-j{\omega}t}dt
\end{equation}
```

It came out to be a text `w`, which I do not want.

[image]

Comment: They *are* different in the picture. You want them to be *more* different?

Comment: @DonaldArseneau, yes, more different

Answer (score 2):

In your 2nd image I think that you have used the clone of Times New Roman in text/math-mode, called:

```
newtxtext, newtxmath
```

---

In fact the output is:

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}


\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
    X(\tau , \omega) =  \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}x(t)w(t - \tau) e^{-j{\omega}t}dt
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

---

If you want have a `\omega` and `w` more different my humble suggestion is to change, without to declare symbols, to `palatino` using `newpxtext` and `newpxmath` as this MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{newpxtext,newpxmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
    X(\tau , \omega) =  \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}x(t)w(t - \tau) e^{-j{\omega}t}dt
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The `\omega` and `w` are more different but the structure of the math symbols are the same of the first my code.

Comment: Sorry, for the second one `palatino`, it is the same as first one, can you have a check please?

Comment: @aan Excuse me but I have not understood your comment. There is a great difference between the w of my first MWE and w of palatino.

Comment: @aan check the name of the math font, is 2nd case is newpxmath not newtxmath (TX vs PX)